Proving an angle is a right angle
I have the below drawing, where:
$$
\begin{align}
\,AB&\,\bot\,\,HC \\ 
\,DA&\,\bot\,\,BC \\ 
\,MG&\,\bot\,\,DA \\ 
\,|CG|\,&=\,|HA| \\ 
\end{align}
$$

$ \color{red}{\text{Q: Prove that}\,MB\,\,\bot\,\,MH\,?}$ 
I can complete a lot of right angle triangles. Nevertheless, nothing is driving the answer.



$$
\frac{\overline{BP}}{\overline{AH}} 
= \frac{\overline{BP}}{\overline{CG}}
= \tan\angle C
= \tan\angle BAD
= \frac{\overline{PM}}{\overline{AM}} 
$$
So: $\Delta AHM \sim \Delta PBM$.
Then $\angle AMH = \angle PMB$.
Then $\angle AMP = \angle HMB = 90^\circ$.

There are a couple of typos in the last two sentences.

@Pranay Updated! Thanks for your correction!!

There's still one typo: $\angle AMH = \angle PMB$.

@Pranay Now corrected it, too. :D

This is probably not the best way, but it works:
Let $\theta = \angle ACB$, $x = HA = GC$, and $y = AG$. Then, since $\angle HAB = \pi/2$, we have
$$
HB^2 = HA^2 + AB^2 = x^2 + (x+y)^2 \tan^2 \theta.
$$
Next, since $\angle HAM = \pi/2 + \theta$, we have
$$
HM^2 = HA^2 + AM^2 - 2 \cdot HA \cdot AM \cdot \cos(\angle HAM) = x^2 + y^2 \sin^2\theta + 2xy\sin^2\theta.
$$
And finally, since $\angle MDB = \pi/2$, we have
$$
MB^2 = MD^2 + DB^2 = x^2 \sin^2 \theta + (x+y)^2(\sec\theta-\cos\theta)^2.
$$
After a bit of algebra, it is easy to verify that
$$
HB^2 = HM^2 + MB^2.
$$
Therefore, $\angle HMB = \pi/2$.

The right triangle paired with equal extensions on the base suggests a dilatory construction for the solution. Call $O$ the midpoint of $BC$, then $OB=OA=OC$. Extend $OA$ to meet the perpendicular at $B$ at $A'$, then define a dilation $O(\frac{OA'}{OA})$ to produce $\triangle{A'B'C'}$ such that $BB'=AA'=CC'$. Then trapezoid $AA'BB'$ is isosceles so that $AB'=A'B$. Set $\alpha=\angle{OCA}$ and $\alpha'=90-\angle{OCA}$, then the angles at point $A$ are:
$$\begin{aligned}
360 &= \angle{CAB}+\angle{BAB'}+\angle{B'AA'}+\angle{A'AC} \\
&= 90+\alpha+\angle{B'AA'}+(90+\alpha') \\
&= 270 + \angle{B'AA'} \\
\\
&\rightarrow \angle{B'AA'}=90
\end{aligned}$$

